# How to perform float division on two usize types in Zig

Tags: casting, division, zig

In my CS class I am learning about hash sets and I am trying to learn Zig at the same time. I'm trying to create my own HashSet class that can hash strings, add them to an index of an array, and handles collisions with a Linked List. To calculate the load factor of a hash set I need to compute entries / available spaces. I can't find a way to perform that float division though, because I can't convert the types to floats no matter what I try...

I'm using zig v0.11.0. This is the relevant struct and function, and what I first tried:

```
pub const LinkedListStringHashSet = struct {
    const Self = @This();

    entries: usize,
    capacity: usize,
    set_array: []?*StringLinkedList,
    allocator: *const Allocator,

    pub fn loadFactor(self: Self) f32 {
        if (self.entries == 0) return @floatFromInt(0);
        return @floatFromInt(self.entries) / @floatFromInt(self.capacity);
    }
}
```

However, I get the error:

```
hash_set.zig:37:16: error: @floatFromInt must have a known result type
        return @floatFromInt(self.entries) / @floatFromInt(self.capacity);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
hash_set.zig:37:16: note: use @as to provide explicit result type
```

As the note says, I tried using `@as` instead:

```
        return @as(f32, self.entries) / @as(f32, self.capacity);
```

however, then I got this error:

```
hash_set.zig:37:29: error: expected type 'f32', found 'usize'
        return @as(f32, self.entries) / @as(f32, self.capacity);
                        ~~~~^~~~~~~~
```

which seems to be relevant to this issue: https://github.com/ziglang/zig/issues/16258. As someone mentioned in the issue, I tried this as well:

```
        return @as(f32, @floatCast(self.entries)) / @as(f32, @floatCast(self.capacity));
```

but that gives me the same error:

```
hash_set.zig:37:40: error: expected float type, found 'usize'
        return @as(f32, @floatCast(self.entries)) / @as(f32, @floatCast(self.capacity));
```

I also tried `@floatCast`, but got the same error.

Asking Bing AI, it suggests me to use @intToFloat, but that function does not exist in v0.11.0.

So... How do I perform a float division on two usize variables in Zig?

Here is the full code of hash_set.zig:

```
const std = @import("std");
const Allocator = @import("std").mem.Allocator;
const StringLinkedList = @import("linked_list.zig").StringLinkedList;

pub const LinkedListStringHashSet = struct {
    const Self = @This();

    entries: usize,
    capacity: usize,
    set_array: []?*StringLinkedList,
    allocator: *const Allocator,

    pub fn init(allocator: *const Allocator, capacity: usize) !Self {
        var new_set_array = try allocator.alloc(?*StringLinkedList, capacity);
        for (new_set_array) |*item| {
            item.* = null;
        }
        return Self {
            .entries = 0,
            .capacity = capacity,
            .set_array = new_set_array,
            .allocator = allocator,
        };
    }

    pub fn deinit(self: Self) void {
        for (self.set_array) |list| {
            if (list) |l| {
                l.deinit();
            }
        }
        self.allocator.free(self.set_array);
    }

    pub fn loadFactor(self: Self) f32 {
        if (self.entries == 0) return @floatFromInt(0);
        return @floatFromInt(self.entries) / @floatFromInt(self.capacity);
    }

    pub fn add(self: *Self, value: []const u8) !void {
        const index = hash(value);

        if (self.set_array[index]) |list| {
            if (!list.contains(value)) {
                try list.add(value);
                self.entries += 1;
            }
        } else {
            const list = try StringLinkedList.init(self.allocator);
            try list.add(value);
            self.set_array[index] = list;
            self.entries += 1;
        }
    }

    pub fn contains(self: Self, value: []const u8) bool {
        const index = hash(value);
        if (self.set_array[index]) |list| {
            return list.contains(value);
        }
        return false;
    }

    pub fn remove(self: *Self, value: []const u8) void {
        const index = hash(value);
        if (self.set_array[index]) |list| {
            defer {
                if (list.head == null) {
                    list.deinit(); 
                    self.set_array[index] = null;
                }
            }
            list.remove(value) catch {};
            self.entries -= 1;
        }
        return; 
    }

    pub fn hash(value: []const u8) usize {
        _ = value;
        return 1;
    }
};


test "Adding and removing elements from a hashset" {
    const allocator = std.testing.allocator;
    var string_set = try LinkedListStringHashSet.init(&allocator, 8);
    defer string_set.deinit();

    try string_set.add("test");
    try std.testing.expect(string_set.entries == 1);
    try std.testing.expect(string_set.contains("test"));

    string_set.remove("test");
    try std.testing.expect(string_set.entries == 0);
    try std.testing.expect(!string_set.contains("test"));

    try string_set.add("hello");
    try std.testing.expect(string_set.contains("hello"));
    try std.testing.expect(string_set.entries == 1);
    try string_set.add("hello");
    try std.testing.expect(string_set.entries == 1);
}
```

Comment: Oh my god, yes, I think so @sigod thank you so much.